# Making generic before_filters a little less ugly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a few before filters which I am using to control access to resources on a resource-by-resource level. The basic idea is as follows:

1. A user can be a `user` or `admin` and can have access to specific resources based on an "accesses" table.
2. Resources/methods can be limited in access to `admin`, `owner`, particular users, or everyone.

This is best illustrated by some code examples. We have 4 application-level methods that are added to the call chain with `before_filter`. Here is the top of an example controller class:

```
before_filter :require_user
before_filter :get_object, :only=>[:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_filter :require_access, :only=>[:show]
before_filter :require_owner, :only=>[:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

As you can see, first we require that a user be logged in to access any method in this controller. Here are 3 fo the methods (defined in application.rb) so that you can see what they look like:

```
 private
 def get_object
   begin
     class_name = controller_name.gsub("Controller","").downcase.singularize
     instance_variable_set "@#{class_name}".to_sym, class_name.capitalize.constantize.find(params[:id])
   rescue
     flash[:error] = "You do not have access to that #{class_name}."
     redirect_to "/" and return
   end
 end

 private
 def require_owner
   class_name = controller_name.gsub("Controller","").downcase.singularize
   accessable = instance_variable_get("@#{class_name.downcase}")
   unless accessable.user == current_user
     flash[:error] = "You do not have access to that #{class_name.downcase}."
     redirect_to "/" and return
   end
 end

 private
 def require_access
   class_name = controller_name.gsub("Controller","").downcase.singularize
   accessable = self.instance_variable_get("@#{class_name.downcase}")
   unless current_user.has_access?(accessable)
     flash[:error] = "You do not have access to that #{class_name.downcase}."
     redirect_to "/" and return
   end
 end
```

This is all *fine*, as far as I can tell, from a coding perspective. But it's just so god-damn ugly! In particular the lines:

```
 class_name = controller_name.gsub("Controller","").downcase.singularize
 obj = instance_variable_get("@#{class_name.downcase}")
```

OR

```
 instance_variable_set "@#{class_name}".to_sym, class_name.capitalize.constantize.find(params[:id])
```

Does anyone know of a bit more elegant way to do what I am doing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if there's a *really* clean way to do this, but here are a few suggestions:

First, create a controller `ResourceController` and have all relevant controllers inherit from it. (If this authorization applies to all controllers you can just use `ApplicationController`.)

Now, implement a private method in the superclass called `model_name` (like your `class_name`) so you don't have to derive it every time you need it. *And*, you should be able to derive it by simply doing this:

```
def model_name
  controller_name.classify
end
```

You can also implement a `model` method in the superclass which returns the actual class:

```
def model
  model_name.constantize
end
```

At this point you might as well also add something like this:

```
def current_object
  model.find(params[:id])
end

def current_object_var_name
  "@#{model_name.underscore}"
end
```

I don't see a quick way around using `instance_variable_get/set` except for always using `@object` or something like it. But if you don't want to do that, those lines are now a little simpler:

```
instance_variable_set current_object_var_name, current_object
obj = instance_variable_get(current_object_var_name)
```

At this point your code should be more readable, and a little prettier.

You might also want to look into what some of the recent Rails authorization plugins are doing, in particular [cancan](http://github.com/ryanb/cancan) and [declarative_authorization](http://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization).

Comment: Oh, great, these do work quite nicely. Only, it should be `controller_name.gsub("Controller","").classify` right?

Comment: Hmm...in my controllers, the `controller_name` method gets rid of the word "controller" for you. In other words, if the controller is `FastCarsController` then `controller_name` returns the string `"fast_cars"`. Try putting this in a view: `<%= controller.controller_name %>` to see exactly what it returns for you.

Comment: Oh, I see. In the past I've used params[:controller] and I didn't realize that controller_name was not yielding the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can do the 2 following things:

1- First remove the 2 other `private` statements, the first one is enough. Remember `private`, `protected` and `public` are just other methods defined in Ruby [`Module`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001641) class.

2- It's better to refactor the code to set that object creation in its method:

```
def create_object
  class_name = controller_name.gsub("Controller","").downcase.singularize
  obj = instance_variable_get("@#{class_name.downcase}")
end

def locate_object
 instance_variable_set "@#{class_name}".to_sym class_name.capitalize.constantize.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining both of your answers I am left with the following fairly clean code, which I really should put into a separate plugin.

```
 private
 def get_resource
   begin
     instance_variable_set current_object_var_name.to_sym, model_name.constantize.find(params[:id])
   rescue
     flash[:error] = "You do not have access to that #{model_name}."
     redirect_to "/" and return
   end
 end

 def require_owner
   unless resource.user == current_user
     flash[:error] = "You do not have access to that  #{model_name}."
     redirect_to "/" and return
   end
 end

 def require_access
   unless current_user.has_access?(resource)
     flash[:error] = "You do not have access to that #{model_name}."
     redirect_to "/" and return
   end
 end

 def resource
   instance_variable_get(current_object_var_name)
 end

 def model_name
   @model_name ||= controller_name.classify
 end

 def current_object_var_name
   "@#{model_name.underscore}"
 end
```